# Best Framework for Developing Rich Desktop Application with 2D & 3D

Tags: java, frameworks, desktop-application

I want to develop an desktop based application which shows 2D & 3D. In earlier version I have used Java 2D & 3D APIs for same.

Now I want to make it with different requirement but want to use rich dashboard, charts, Forms, 2D & 3D movement etc....

I have searched and bit learned Eclipse RCP, but I found it very very complex.

I also found QT framework by Nokia, but haven't tried.

Can any body suggest which are the best combinations to archive my requirements?

Answer (score 2):

Have you heared about javaFX? Have a look at: http://javafx.com/

Also if you want a great tool for developing desktop GUI i would recommend you JFormDesigner http://www.formdev.com/ (I am not sure can you do 3d stuff with it)